# Connecting flight from Pakistan to Abu Dhabi to Thailand

Tags: transit-visas, connecting-flights, abu-dhabi, etihad

I have a connecting flight from Pakistan to Thailand. My stay is in Abu Dhabi for 3.5 hours. I will land in Abu Dhabi at terminal A and my next flight is from terminal T3. Do I need a transit visa? And do I need to take my luggage or it will transfer itself to next flight?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? What are the airlines involved?

Comment: @jcaron Etihad airways, yes same ticket

Comment: What did Etihad say when you asked them? https://www.etihad.com/en-gb/fly-etihad/visas

Comment: What date are you travelling on? You have to change terminals only if you travel between November 9 and 14: before that all Etihad flights are in Terminals 1/3 and after that all in Terminal A.

Answer (score 4):

Given that both flights are on the same ticket:

- Your checked luggage will be "checked-through" to your final destination: you'll drop your bags in Pakistan, and will not see them before you reach Thailand. They will be transferred from one flight to the other.
- You are likely to get both boarding passes at your origin airport. In some cases this isn't possible, and then you need to pick up your second boarding pass from a transit desk in Abu Dhabi.
- You will not go through passport control in Abu Dhabi. As you are remaining airside and staying less than 12 hours, you don't need a visa or hotel booking.
- Terminal A (the mid-field terminal) is brand new and hasn't opened yet. Etihad will gradually move their flights from T1/T3 to Terminal A between November 9 and November 14. If you travel before that you will stay in T1/T3 (which are directly connected). If you travel after that you will stay in Termainal A. If you travel during the move, then [Etihad tell us that there will be a shuttle every 10 minutes between Terminal A and Terminal 3](https://www.etihad.com/en-om/fly-etihad/airport-information/terminal-a-information).